# What is this instrument on the ISS?

Tags: iss, instrument, identify-this-object

In [this image](https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/165304main_image_feature_719_ys_full.jpg) (NASA [original source](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/shuttle/sts-116/html/s116e05983.html)) from the International Space Station. what is the "lightning rod"-like instrument at the end of the mast in the upper right of the photo?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Emitter antenna for the Orbital Mind Control Lasers.

Comment: It looks more like the Space Trailer Hitch Ball....

Comment: Fascinating. Does anyone know what landmass that is on the photo?

Comment: @r41n It's New Zealand looking North over Pegasus Bay with Christchurch to the bottom-left of the bay. https://goo.gl/maps/A2niy3xogG92

Comment: Looks more like the subspace transceiver antenna array to me...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the [Floating Potential Measurement Unit](http://www.sdl.usu.edu/programs/fpmu) (FPMU).

Specifically, the ball is the Wide Langmuir Probe.

[image]

picture from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiSpK3K2I_SAhVhxlQKHcnLCrcQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fntrs.nasa.gov%2Farchive%2Fnasa%2Fcasi.ntrs.nasa.gov%2F20090025959.pdf&usg=AFQjCNETGBTujNh4qO70r35ZANvHfqyzqw&sig2=D6QyVN0qVYB4bpw1yI4R-w)

> The FPMU was installed by ISS crewmembers, during an Extra Vehicular
> Activity (EVA), on the starboard (Sl) truss of the ISS in early August
> 2006. The system is based on past USU/SDL space instruments and incorporates a Floating Potential Probe, multiple Langmuir Probes, and
> a Plasma Frequency Probe into one sensor suite.
>
> The FPMU is used to correct the charging models of the station each
> time a new section is added to the structure. By providing feedback on
> the effectiveness of steps taken to control charging, the FPMU helps
> ensure a safe working environment for the astronauts.

USU = Utah State University

SDL = Space Dynamics Laboratory

For more info about *how it works, not what it is*, see my answer to this question: [How do spacecraft measure their own charge?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20160/how-do-spacecraft-measure-their-own-charge/20163#20163) .

At some point since the FPMU was originally installed, it has been moved to Camera Port 6 on the P1 truss, as pointed out in this question: [Identifying Antenna-Like Object with Gold Orb on ISS](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/60019/identifying-antenna-like-object-with-gold-orb-on-iss) and as confirmed in this [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/View_of_the_ISS_taken_during_Crew-2_flyaround_%28ISS066-E-080762%29.jpg) linked from there and annotated by me:

[image]

Comment: So it's a *space* lightning rod!