# Identifying Antenna-Like Object with Gold Orb on ISS

Tags: iss, identify-this-object

Many photos of the Neutron Star Interior Composition ExploreR (NICER) show it partially obscured by an object which looks like a golden orb on a poll. What is this object?
[image: Object in front of NICER]

**Attempted Solution**

Zooming in on a [high resolution image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/View_of_the_ISS_taken_during_Crew-2_flyaround_%28ISS066-E-080762%29.jpg) of the whole station, I think this is a "T" shaped object, viewed from the side.
[image: "T" shaped object]

If so, it would appear to be on the P1 truss.
[image]

However, I cannot find a diagram with this object labeled.

Comment: Hi, welcome to space stack exchange. Don't feel bad about getting your question closed as a duplicate, it just means someone else asked the exact same question. The answer should help you out.

Comment: You're right that it's currently mounted in Camera Port 6 on the P1 truss. They must have moved it since it was originally installed. I'll edit the old answer.

Comment: described further here https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20163/12102