# Problems with spaceflight high voltage

Tags: low-earth-orbit, spacecraft-charging

What problem exists if the surface of the satellite is at a high positive potential in LEO?

What is the maximum voltage it could withstand?

is there any document about it?

Comment: I think an answer may be able to draw partly from information in [How do spacecraft measure their own charge?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20160/12102)  and [Why aren't magnetic bearings used more frequently in reaction wheels?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29769/12102) and [Neutralization of ions in the ion thruster](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45504/12102) and the answers there

Comment: and [Is a spacecraft able to measure it's current electric charge in some way?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20156/12102) and [How is charge dissipated in ion-propulsed spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20133/12102) and finally [Strategies for combating ESD and ground plane potential shifts on spacecraft charging?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5062/12102)

Comment: Try this link, http://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/SciTechBook/series3/17JKeyDocs.pdf, also referenced from my answer to this question https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5062/strategies-for-combating-esd-and-ground-plane-potential-shifts-on-spacecraft-cha/13802#13802

Comment: Here https://standards.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/standards/OCE/PUBLISHED/Baseline3/2020_12_29_nasa-hdbk-4007_w-change_3_revalidated_0.pdf is a NASA paper about this theme, 147 pages

Comment: @Puffin bounty expires in three days (plus 1 day grace period when it's not visible but can still be awarded)