Thrust Impulse graph for specific engine type
I've seen many graphs for nuclear, chemical and airbreathing engine.
However I have not seen a good depiction of electric engines such as xenon ion engines, argon thrusters, lithium, etc.
This question is in two parts:

Where can I find a good depiction and how was it determined.

What variables are involved in the adjustment of thrust and impulse for an electric engine.



This is going to depend what you mean by a "depiction". 1) All forms of propulsion with a reaction mass (propellant) follow the same relationships regarding thrust and Isp so that includes all the types you have mentioned. This previous answer https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14201/could-oxygen-be-used-in-a-resistojet-in-a-vacuum-environment/14203?r=SearchResults&s=12%7C9.5672#14203  applies that to a resistojet though the principal is the same everywhere.


the widely varying concept is how the power in the beam is created at the thruster and this is where each type of electric thruster (mostly gridded ion engines and hall effect thrusters) and hybrid thrusters (e.g. hydrazine arcjets and hydrazine resistojets) will have its own electrical parameters; e.g. a grid acceleration voltage is meaningless for a hall thruster.


Cheers, I'll see if anything pops up in the answers, but otherwise I may close this question.
